# Generic method to take different class objects

Tags: java, generics

I have 3 class(techspecs, packages, and features) objects where they all share the same fields. The fields are big and instead of repeating setting the fields of each field 3 times(which ends up looking like duplicates), I would like to pass the class objects into one method that uses the generic object to setting the object fields.

I tried passing the class object as a generic but then i dont have access to its members. This is what i tried

```
  Packages packagesFeatures = new Packages();
  TechSpecs techSpecsFeature = new TechSpecs();
  packagesFeatures  =  addFeatures(Packages.class, packagesFeatures, vehFeatures);
  techSpecsFeature  = addFeatures(TechSpecs.class, techSpecsFeature, vehFeatures);
```

Then

```
    private <T> T addFeatures(Class<T> clazz, T obj,  VehicleFeature vehFeatures) {

    T inst = null;

    try {
        inst = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (inst instanceof Packages) {
      obj = (T) new Packages();


    }
    if(inst instanceof TechSpecs){
        obj = (T) new TechSpecs();
    }

    if(inst instanceof Features){
        obj = (T) new Features();
    }


    //then somthing like:
    //obj.setFeatureId(vehFeatures.getFeatureId());
    // obj.setFeatureKey(vehFeatures.getFeatureKey());
    // obj.setFeatureCode(vehFeatures.getFeatureCode());

    return obj;
```

**EDIT**
Each of the 3 classes extend BaseFeatures

```
public abstract class BaseFeatures {
private String featureId;
private String featureKey;
private String featureCode;
private String subSectionId;
private String subSectionName;
private String featureIdName;
private Integer subSectionRank;
private Integer featureImgClassificationId;
private String featureImgClassification;
private boolean has3DAnimation;
private String sectionId;
private String searchKeys;
private String description;
private String featureName;
private double featureRank;
private String geoId;
private String ecc;
private String specSegments;
private String featureIconType;
private String featureIconText;
private double featureValue;
private boolean standardCertain;
private boolean built;
private List<String> featureKeyAnswers;
private boolean isNumeric;
private boolean adasFeature;
private List<String> icCodeAnswers;
private String featureKeyNoBrand;
private List<StyleInfo> styles;
private List<String> optionCodes;
private List<String> changeOptions;
```

//getters and setters.

Here is one of the classes.

```
public class TechSpecs extends BaseFeatures {

private String techSpecs;


public void setTechSpecs(String techSpecs) {
    this.techSpecs = techSpecs;
}

public String getTechSpecs(){
    return techSpecs;
}

}
```

All of these fields need to be set in the class object of all 3 classes

**EDIT 2**

VehicleFeature Class is a standalone class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class VehicleFeature {
private String section;
private String subSection;
private String featureName;
private String subSectionId;
private String sectionName;
private String subSectionName;
```

Comment: "they all share the same fields" - have you considered creating a Java `interface` to make this information available to the compiler?

Comment: If you could find a name for the *big fields*, then maybe you come to a new class, which  *Packages* and *Techspec* may extend? In the next step you could think about **prefere composition over inheritence**

Comment: each of the 3 classes extends ABSTRACT class baseFeatures. for example: public class TechSpecs extends BaseFeatures {

Comment: „*...The fields are big...*“ — What exactly do you mean by that? „*Big*“ in what way, precisely? „*...each of the 3 classes extends ABSTRACT class baseFeatures...*“ — Feel like sharing the basics of that?

Comment: i added an edit

Comment: i also added techspec class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I would simplify your *`addFeatures(...)`* method to something like:

```
private <T> T addFeatures(Class<T> clazz, BaseFeatures theseFeatures) {

    T obj = null;
    
    try {
        
        obj = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(BaseFeatures.class).newInstance(theseFeatures);              
        
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException roe) {
        
        roe.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return obj;
}
```

I'd add these two constructors to *`BaseFeatures`*:

```
public abstract class BaseFeatures{

    protected String featureId;
    
    protected String featureKey;
    
    protected String featureCode;

    /*...*/
    
    protected BaseFeatures(String featureId, String featureKey, String featureCode){
        this.featureId = featureId;
        this.featureKey = featureKey;
        this.featureCode = featureCode;
    }
    
    protected BaseFeatures(BaseFeatures features){
        this.featureId = features.featureId ;
        this.featureKey = features.featureKey;
        this.featureCode = features.featureCode;
    }

    /*...*/
}
```

You can [*see how that implementation would actually work*](https://jdoodle.com/a/2b3Y), here:

```
public class BigAssFields {

    /* ... */

    static public void main(String ... args){

        BigAssFields bLike = new BigAssFields();
        
        VehicleFeature vehFeatures = new VehicleFeature("what", "the actual", "Feature");
    
        TechSpecs bigTechSpecs =  bLike.addFeatures(TechSpecs.class, vehFeatures);
    
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: P.S. While I was at it, I went ahead [*and implemented that one method as*](https://jdoodle.com/a/2b3Y) _`Optional<T> addFeatures(...)`_ instead of returning _`null`_ potentially.

Comment: let me play with this and i will get back to yo later. Thanks

Comment: VehicleFeature is not part of the BaseFeatures class. I get error : VehicleFeature is not compatable with BaseFeatures

Comment: Are you getting that error in [*that jdoodle project I shared*](https://jdoodle.com/a/2b3Y)? Please share a snippet of how you called it?

Comment: Looking at the implimentation link i have more work to do. I will get back later sorry

Comment: No rush. I'm just puzzling over what you mean by „*I get error : ...*“ and „*...I added a second edit for VehicleFeature...*“. I'm not seeing any change in the project I shared. When I click on the blue ***Execute*** button in that project, I see the expected: _`VehicleFeature [...]`_ and
_`TechSpecs [...]`_ lines in _`stdout`_ of the project.

Comment: This works. I had to chnage one little thing but i think this will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Helped me so much..

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped you. Thank you for giving it your check mark.

Comment: is it possible to create a builder design pattern class for baseFeatures since it now has a ton of sets in its constructor? I know baseFeatures is abstract so it wont let me.

Comment: I'm in the middle of something else at the moment. You're probably familiar with [_Lombok_](https://projectlombok.org/). Right? Can you use that in your project?

Comment: I might be able to use it. I dont know anything about lombok. Is there something i could google to help me with this current thing i want to do?

Comment: i know i have asked too much from you. Thanks for all your help

Comment: [*This site's  guides*](https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok) are usually pretty easy to follow. Or just Google „*Lombok tutorial*“ if that one isn't for you. Also, what's the highest version of Java you're allowed to use on your project?